# Using the definition of the limit of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm currently learning about sequences and their limits. The definition of a limit I'm given is:

$L$ is said to be the limit of a sequence $\{x_n\}$ if $\forall\epsilon > 0$,  $\exists N_{\epsilon} \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $\forall n \geq N_{\epsilon}$, $|x_n - L| < \epsilon$

I'm working through the following exercise:

Prove with the definition of the limit of a sequence that $$lim\frac{(n^2-1)}{(2n^2+3)}= \frac{1}{2}$$

So far what I've done is attempted to find $N_{\epsilon}$:

I've reduced $\bigg{|}\frac{(n^2-1)}{(2n^2+3)} - \frac{1}{2}\bigg{|}$ to $\frac{5}{(4n^2+6)}$. But I'm not sure how to proceed with the $n^2$. I think it's along the lines of:
$$\frac{5}{(4n^2+6)} < \frac{5}{(4n^2)}<\frac{5}{4n} < \epsilon$$

Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: It's okay. If you leave the square in, you get a smaller $N_\epsilon$, but since you just need to find any $N_\epsilon$ that works, it doesn't matter.

Comment: could you explain your "reduced to"?

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to include $-\frac{1}{2} $in the absolute value.

Comment: That's right! Remember, when you see "there exists", all you want to do is find an N that works or pick it so that it works. Given the $N$ you tried for that particular $ \epsilon$, does it work? Try it!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are going in the right direction.

$\frac{5}{4n^2+6} < \frac{5}{4n^2}<\frac{9}{4n^2}=\left(\frac{3}{2n}\right)^2 < \epsilon \; \quad $ if $n>N_{\epsilon}=\frac{3}{2\sqrt{\epsilon}}$